# Sequelize association - hasOne Returns all the rows

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

I am working on the `sequalize association - hasOne` variant. I got all the rows from the `USER` table instead of returning the rows from the `system_admin` table. Is this the expected behaviour?

```
const User = sq.define('user', {
    firstName: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    lastName: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    email: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    password: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    phoneCode: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    phone: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    is_deleted: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
    is_active: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true }
}, { 
    tableName: 'users',
    indexes: [
    {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['email', 'is_deleted', 'is_active']
    }
] 
});

const SystemAdmin = sq.define('system_admin', {
    categories_id: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
    user_id: {type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
    is_deleted: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false }
}, { tableName: 'system_admin'});

User.hasOne(SystemAdmin, { as: "system_admin", foreignKey: "user_id", });
SystemAdmin.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: "id",
  as: "users",
});

const userss = await User.findAll({ include: ["system_admin"] });
console.log(userss.length);
```

I am getting all the user rows from the `findAll` method. Can you please suggest the appropriate syntax to fetch only system Admin user rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use an extended syntax of the `include` option and indicate that you need INNER JOIN (i.e. all records in one table should have the related ones in the other table):

```js
const userss = await User.findAll({ include: [{
  model: SystemAdmin,
  // true - INNER JOIN, false - LEFT OUTER JOIN
  required: true
}] });
```

In this case `hasOne` shows that you can get all users but probably not all of them have corresponding records in `SystemAdmin` so you need to indicate explicitly that you need only those who has a records in `SystemAdmin`.